# Determine three variables with the three given equations

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

With the positive integers $a, b$ and $c$, we form the numbers

$ x=60a+13b$   and   $y=60a+11c$

Determine all valid choices for $a, b$ and $c$, for which the equation

$4x^2-y^2=2020$

applies and give proof that there is not any another valid solution.r

Comment: Please show some of your thoughts and work.

Comment: You can insert the first two equations into the third one and you get: $10800a^2+6240ab+169b^2-1320ac-121c^2=2020$
Plotting this in 3D is possible and I tried but it didn‘t reveal anything useful.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
since $y^2=4x^2-2020$ is even, so is $y$.

Write $y = 2y'$ and we now have $x^2-y'^2 = 505 = (x-y')(x+y')$.

Since both $x$ and $y'$ are positive integers, and that $505 = 5 \times 101$, there are only a few choices for $x$ and $y'$.

Comment: If $y=2y‘$, then it would be $2x^2-y^2=1010$, though. With your equations, the results are $x=53$ and $y=96$, which can‘t be right.

Comment: No. $y=2y' \implies y^2=4y'^2$.

Comment: Oh, shoot. But then I got $x-y‘=5$ and $x+y‘=101$, the results still don‘t fit the first two equations, right?

Comment: This pair is not the only solution.

Comment: God bless you, bro. Thanks for being so patient, too haha

Answer (score 1):

$4x^2 - y^2 = (2x + y) (2x - y) = 2020 = 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 101$

As $(2x + y)$ and $(2x - y)$ will both be even or both odd, The only way the product to be 2020 is if both are even.

So, $2x + y = 1010$ and $2x - y = 2$

Or $2x + y = 202$ and $2x - y = 10$

The first one gives you $x = 253, y = 504$. That is the only answer that works when you check.

$x = 60a + 13b = 253$

As $60a$ is multiple of $10$, $13b$ needs to have $3$ in one's place. That gives you unique $a$ and $b$. Then use $y$ to solve for $c$.

Comment: Thank you, too. The explanation at the end is clear and elegant!